# How do I use append to add the answer to an array for registration from input so I can log in using the answer from the input?

Tags: python, arrays, class, object, if-statement

I tried using uname.append(uname) to add the answer from input to the array above, My finished code should have a. main page: user will be greeted and asked to proceed to; b. Registration page user will be able to create a name only c. Log-in page, user will be able to log-in using the name he/she registered. I couldn't figure out a way to use array to solve this. it will have an error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' if i run it.

```
uname = []

def reg():
    uname = input("save your username here: ")
    uname.append(uname)
    print ("Welcome user!")

def log():
    print ("This is the Login Page")
    askuname = input("please enter your username: ")
    if uname == askuname:
         print ("you have successfully logged in!")
    else:
        print ("Your username does not exist")

def main():
    print ("Hello User, What would you like to do?")
    print ("1 - Register your name")
    print ("2 - Login")

    x = input("Please select the corresponding number to proceed: ")
    if x == "1":
        print()
        reg()
    elif x == "2":
        print("/n")
        log()
    else:
        print("incorrect input")

main()
```

I went and searched for ways to store the input in the array (uname = []) but failed it always results in AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: do you see how your naming of variables may have caused the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occuring with this:

```
uname = []

def reg():
    uname = input("save your username here: ")
    uname.append(uname)
    print ("Welcome user!")
```

The reason why it is occurring is that you have the same variable name in two different scopes (global and local to the function). When you are trying to change something a function if the variable is called the same thing will try to use the function's local scoped variable. In this case that local variable is a `str` object which does not have an `append()` function to it, while the actual variable that you want to use is named the same in a different scope.

The way to fix it would be to change either the list name or the variable that you save the input to, such as:

```
uname = []

def reg():
    username = input("save your username here: ")
    uname.append(username)
    print ("Welcome user!")
```

Comment: how do i do this? for the Log-in page, user will be able to log-in using the name he/she registered

Comment: @mamamia123 I gave you a fix for the problem -- the second code snippet.

Comment: when i type the same answer for the log in page it says your username does not exist even though I used append to add the username to the array, it should say you have successfully logged in!

Comment: @mamamia123 that's a secondary problem -- change `if uname == askuname:` to `if askuname in uname:` though this assumes that the elements will both have the same case. This is checking that the askuname is inside uname while the previous version was checking the equality of uname and askuname (which they are not equal as uname is a list object and askuname is a str)